# Excel pace formula gives incorrect answers

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with a basic pace calculator in Excel.

Pace is calculated by time/distance.
So in A2 we have time in (hh:mm) format. B2 is distance, C2 is a helper column of time in minutes =(A2*1440) and pace is D2 with =C2/B2.

[image: basic pace formula]

So far so good. If I enter a time of 00:30 and a distance of 5km I get a pace of 6:00 /km which is what I expected. However, if I use a longer time and distance of 2:59 and 27.42 I get a pace of 6:53 but it should be 06:31 (if I use an online pace calculator to check my results).

I suspect I'm calculating the minutes of the pace as a decimal rather than seconds. Also the image above should show a pace of 6:17.99, not 6:30

Comment: It doesn't show time 6:30, it shows 6.3 (6 point 3). You divide number by number but somehow expect result to be time instead of number.

Comment: Exactly and if you want to show as `6:18:00` then format the cells as ``[h]:mm:ss;@` after dividing the pace value with `1440` and for the rest it gives the exact output you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, 6.3 is correct answer just not in your desired format.

If you have your A column formatted in "hh:mm". Just simply divide A/B and use correct formatting. Either hh:mm:ss.000 or mm:ss.000 . Result:

[image]